# Why does using std::move on a unique_ptr destroy it?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

So my understanding of move semantics is that this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class hello {
public:
    ~hello() {
        std::cout << "destroyed" << std::endl;
    }
    hello() {
        std::cout << "constructred" << std::endl;
    }
};


void takecontrol(std::unique_ptr<hello>&& ptr) {

    ptr.release();
}

int main()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<hello>();


}
```

should create a memory leak and only print "constructed."

yet when run (http://cpp.sh/2upqq) it destroys the object!

To me it seems it should be moved into `ptr` in `takecontrol` then released then not deleted so it shouldn't ever be destroyed.

What am I missing?

Comment: "What am I missing?" The call to `takecontrol`, probably?

Comment: You never call `takecontrol`.

Comment: Your program with a call to `takecontrol`: http://cpp.sh/9qh3u

Comment: lol..............

Comment: BTW, as an editorial comment, you don't have any `std::move` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the call to this function into main

```
int main()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<hello>();

    takecontrol(std::move(ptr));
}
```

you get the behaviour you expect.

Comment: Wow I looked over this snippet so many times and somehow missed it...